# Send DDC/CI commands to monitor on Windows using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, controls, monitor

I'm working on a program to automatically change the brightness of my displays directly using DDC/CI. Currently I'm using ScreenBright's command line arguments to do this just to get things working, but I would like to move to doing it directly now that things are working.

There is a Windows API, the [Monitor Configuration API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692962(v=vs.85).aspx), to do this, but I don't know how to integrate this into my project, and any usage is only given in C++. The only other thing I can find is doing this from Python, which is no use either.

Any help would be much appreciated.